# had my periods and didn't do ghusl

Tags: salat, fiqh, ghusl

i am 13 years old and i committed a huge sin. 
once after i got my periods, i got too lazy and didn't do ghusl, and i didn't even do a single prayer for the next 2 months. then, the next month after i got my periods i felt very guilty so i did ghusl and started praying like normal. should i do something different? is there a particular way i can repent for this sin? 
also i heard somewhere that if a person hasn't performed a single prayer for more than 40 days then he/she is not a muslim anymore. is this true? I'm scared and i don't know what to do, please help.

Comment: @RobertColumbia It's not really absurd, there's a significant portion of Islamic scholars who think that purposely not performing prayer on time just once makes you a kafir.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu'Alaykum O Rahmatullah O Barokatuh? 
How are you? 
Whatever happens in the past is the past, in the Qur'an Allah said when my slave repent to me I forgive them. You can ask does Allah forgive sins of the past? Of course yes! Allah is the most Merciful. 
Let me give you a example: When someone become a Muslim Allah(swt) doesn't hold  their sin, he forgive them and he makes all of those sin into good deed. Unbelievable, how merciful is Allah. AllahuAkbar! 
Whenever a person fall into sin he/she has to repent to Allah that's the only way out.
Keep doing good deed improving in everything you can and  40 days you have heard wrong. The limits is up to 40 days. The only way you stop been Muslim is to stop Salah, if you mist you Salah and the didn't make it up that kufr and you left Islam according to Islamic scholar. 
Also when you ask don't write you age for you safety. 
Assalamu'Alaykum O Rahmatullah O Barokatuh!